# Commit uncommited file in git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I am a beginner with GIT and have my repository on BitBucket. A few days ago I started to commit my code to the repository. I am not sure of the command I used in the terminal but it wasn't showing any progress after which I closed the terminal.

Now, I noticed that a portion of the code is there in my repository. I have to upload some of files that didn't go in the repository the last time. What command is used for that purpose?

Comment: Are your trying to push your code to bitbucket or do a local commit ?

Comment: `git add .` in the root of the project

Comment: @ashutoshraina: I am not sure about the difference. If you could give a little more detial about this

Comment: @user1240679 the answer below should help you out. Basically git add will start tracking your files. Git commints are local and push is used you need to get the repository out to the remote server ( in your case bitbucket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting to use a tool it's always a good idea to study it. You should at least read the [git tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html), a [git guide](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/everyday.html), and maybe even the [git glossary](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) to know what terms you'll encounter often really mean.

Short answer: `git add --help`, `git commit --help`, `git push --help`